# Dotenv not availabe in routes.rb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dotenv, ruby-dotenv

eversince I started using Dotenv inside my routes.rb I get weird errors.

I'm using `gem 'dotenv-rails', '~> 2.0.0'`

`routes.rb`:

```
constraints(host: ENV.fetch("SHORTENER_DOMAIN")) do
  get ':id', to: 'shortener#redirect'
end
```

Terminal:

```
username:~/Sites/my_app$ rails s
/Users/username/Sites/my_app/config/routes.rb:4:in 'fetch': key not found: "SHORTENER_DOMAIN" (KeyError)
    from /Users/username/Sites/my_app/config/routes.rb:4:in 'block in <top (required)>'

username:~/Sites/my_app$ rails s
=> Booting Thin
=> Rails 4.2.5 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Thin web server (v1.6.4 codename Gob Bluth)
Maximum connections set to 1024
Listening on localhost:3000, CTRL+C to stop
```

I did not do anything between these two `rails s`, just repeated it and it worked. It's really strange.

This is where I'm loading `dotenv`:

```
Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)
Dotenv::Railtie.load
```

Anyone knows what's happening?

---UPDATE---

I have googled and tried everything. It still appears only in development environment for all `rails`, `rake` commands.

Has anyone had this problem? It's driving me crazy.

Comment: You are using [`Dotenv`](https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv) gem or built-in ruby accessor for [`environment variables.`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/ENV.html)?

Comment: ok, where is you call `Dotenv::Railtie.load` method or `require 'dotenv';
Dotenv.load` as it noticed in the documentation?

Comment: Oh, I guess I placed it wrong. Moved it all the way up to `Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)` and now it's working. Thanks! However, still strange that it sometimes works and sometimes not.

Comment: No, it's not helping. Just tried to run `rails c` and the message was back. Worked after 3 times.

Comment: This is getting really frustrating, no one?

Comment: any update on this or what worked

Comment: Well, it turns out without doing anything fancy, it started working on its own. In dev and also in production(after a couple releases).